# htop enters uninterruptible disk sleep forever while reading zombie thread info from proc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, operating-system, zombie-process

I have a system with a Zombie process (python3 running multiple threads) which has many threads. The problem is, the application `htop` gets stuck in uninterruptible disk sleep (D). `strace`ing `htop` indicates while scanning the `/proc/ZPID/task/TID/cmdline` I have manually confirmed this with `cat /proc/ZPID/task/TID/cmdline`, which goes into D as well.

That indicates that this is not `htop` specific. The title has `htop` because the issue started from it. The details are mentioned below.

The `htop` and any such application reading this pseudofile (or others possibly in the subtree) gets stuck in state D. Therefore as the users execute `htop` it accumulates. Running `htop` in a loop of just `cat`ting those pseudofiles in a loop will get the system to a halt, which can only be resolved by pulling the cord.

I identified the parent process of the Zombie and killed the parent process (it is `bash` running in `tmux`) so that it gets reparented to `init`, in this case `systemd`. Although, I expected the child to be reaped but although the `python3` Zombie process has now a PPID of 1, it **still** is in a Zombie state. Also, all those `htop`, `cat` etc. which reads the Zombie processe's `/proc/ZPID/task/TID/cmdline` is still in D state.

Therefore it seems that there is no other way except to reboot the system to get rid of this Zombie.

## Question

1. How to stop the `htop` (or any other process accessing those pseudo-files) instances to go into uninterruptible disk sleep for ever.
2. Is there any way to make init/systemd to reap the Zombie `python3` process without removing?

Although I can understand that there is nothing much which can be done now, but it will be good if someone can at least help me to understand exactly why the system ran into this situation.

Below are some information about the system which may be of help.

## Debug

#### OS version

```
head -n2 /etc/os-release

NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
```

#### Kernel version

```
uname -srvm
Linux 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64
```

I have tried sending `SIGCHLR` to 1 (which it shouldn't need). I tried to to `strace`, `pstack` but no help.

#### /proc/PID/status dump

```
Name:   htop
State:  D (disk sleep)
Tgid:   23395
Ngid:   0
Pid:    23395
PPid:   1
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    1005    1005    1005    1005
Gid:    1005    1005    1005    1005
FDSize: 256
Groups: 27 1005 
NStgid: 23395
NSpid:  23395
NSpgid: 23395
NSsid:  23370
VmPeak:    27040 kB
VmSize:    27008 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:      4948 kB
VmRSS:      3212 kB
VmData:     1700 kB
VmStk:       132 kB
VmExe:       156 kB
VmLib:      3548 kB
VmPTE:        72 kB
VmPMD:        12 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
HugetlbPages:          0 kB
Threads:        1
SigQ:   20/515408
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000003
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000000000
SigCgt: 0000000008084402
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 0000003fffffffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
Seccomp:        0
Cpus_allowed:   ffff,ffffffff
Cpus_allowed_list:      0-47
Mems_allowed:   00000000,00000003
Mems_allowed_list:      0-1
voluntary_ctxt_switches:        1
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:     1
```

Point to note here there's only 1 voluntary and non-voluntary context switch. Therefore the process is going nowhere and running for weeks.

#### /proc/PID/sched dump

```
htop (23395, #threads: 1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
se.exec_start                                :    5618689963.080376
se.vruntime                                  :     329703377.411193
se.sum_exec_runtime                          :            42.996258
se.statistics.sum_sleep_runtime              :             0.000000
se.statistics.wait_start                     :             0.000000
se.statistics.sleep_start                    :             0.000000
se.statistics.block_start                    :    5618689963.080376
se.statistics.sleep_max                      :             0.000000
se.statistics.block_max                      :             0.000000
se.statistics.exec_max                       :             3.999987
se.statistics.slice_max                      :             0.000000
se.statistics.wait_max                       :             0.002956
se.statistics.wait_sum                       :             0.002956
se.statistics.wait_count                     :                    3
se.statistics.iowait_sum                     :             0.000000
se.statistics.iowait_count                   :                    0
se.nr_migrations                             :                    2
se.statistics.nr_migrations_cold             :                    0
se.statistics.nr_failed_migrations_affine    :                    0
se.statistics.nr_failed_migrations_running   :                    0
se.statistics.nr_failed_migrations_hot       :                    0
se.statistics.nr_forced_migrations           :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups                     :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_sync                :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_migrate             :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_local               :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_remote              :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_affine              :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_affine_attempts     :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_passive             :                    0
se.statistics.nr_wakeups_idle                :                    0
avg_atom                                     :            21.498129
avg_per_cpu                                  :            21.498129
nr_switches                                  :                    2
nr_voluntary_switches                        :                    1
nr_involuntary_switches                      :                    1
se.load.weight                               :                 1024
se.avg.load_sum                              :             47861560
se.avg.util_sum                              :             47860718
se.avg.load_avg                              :                 1002
se.avg.util_avg                              :                 1002
se.avg.last_update_time                      :     5618689963080376
policy                                       :                    0
prio                                         :                  120
clock-delta                                  :                   18
mm->numa_scan_seq                            :                    0
numa_pages_migrated                          :                    1
numa_preferred_nid                           :                   -1
total_numa_faults                            :                   22
current_node=0, numa_group_id=0
numa_faults node=0 task_private=0 task_shared=0 group_private=0 group_shared=0
numa_faults node=1 task_private=0 task_shared=0 group_private=0 group_shared=0
```

Below is `/proc/PID/syscall` dump.

```
0 0x5 0x7ffd47db2970 0x1000 0x5 0x0 0x1e 0x7ffd47db28a8 0x7f836a517260
```

The process is suck at syscall `0` which translates to `__NR_read`, when I search `grep -e "0$" /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64.h`.

#### /proc/PID/stack dump

```
[<ffffffff8140e3c4>] call_rwsem_down_read_failed+0x14/0x30
[<ffffffff81284f6e>] proc_pid_cmdline_read+0xae/0x530
[<ffffffff8121380b>] __vfs_read+0x1b/0x40
[<ffffffff81213de6>] vfs_read+0x86/0x130
[<ffffffff81214b35>] SyS_read+0x55/0xc0
[<ffffffff8184efc8>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x1c/0xbb
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

Therefore the execution is in `call_rwsem_down_read_failed` right now. From the code it looks like it blocks on a semaphore(?) (Ref https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.16/arch/x86/lib/rwsem.S#L89 , https://lkml.org/lkml/2010/11/23/272)

In the system there is one semaphore in use (as per `ipcs`) and it belongs to `/sbin/iscsid`

**UPDATE**

I have tried to list the threads of the Zombie process using `ps -Teo pid,ppid,state,comm,args $ZOMBIEPID` , it does not block. `strace`ing the previous command indicates that `ps` never accesses `/proc/ZPID/task/TID/cmdline` . I think `ps` just gets the TIDs from this directory and gets the cmdline contents from `/proc/TID/cmdline`. Also, other pseudofiles in `/proc/ZPID/task/TID/` are readable.

I read the Zombie processe's TID syscall files using a script. I think it explains more.

Below, **44529** is the Zombie process, rest are the tasks. They all are stuck in the syscal 202, which is `__NR_futex`, therefore they are waiting on a userspace mutex. Note that the `python3` instance was running multi-threaded code, which uses the python's [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) library. The main thread has -1 as the syscall value.

```
tid: 44529, syscall: -1 0x7ffca68c6e68 0x7f74ca51914b
tid: 45111, syscall: -1 0x7f7468ffc938 0x7f74c9309d30
tid: 45112, syscall: 202 0x7f74c886133c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861300 0x2 0x7f746b7fdee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45113, syscall: 202 0x7f74c88613bc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861300 0x2 0x7f74adffeee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45114, syscall: 202 0x7f74c886143c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861400 0x2 0x7f74b07ffee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45115, syscall: 202 0x7f74c88614bc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861400 0x2 0x7f74c5d9dee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45116, syscall: 202 0x7f74c886153c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861500 0x2 0x7f74c559cee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45117, syscall: 202 0x7f74c88615bc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861500 0x2 0x7f74c4b58ee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45118, syscall: 202 0x7f74c886163c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861600 0x2 0x7f74c001eee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45119, syscall: 202 0x7f74c88616bc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861600 0x2 0x7f74bf81dee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45120, syscall: 202 0x7f74c886173c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861700 0x2 0x7f74bf01cee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45121, syscall: 202 0x7f74c88617bc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861700 0x2 0x7f74be81bee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45122, syscall: 202 0x7f74c886183c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861800 0x2 0x7f74be01aee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45123, syscall: 202 0x7f74c88618bc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861800 0x2 0x7f74bd15cee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45124, syscall: 202 0x7f74c886193c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861900 0x2 0x7f74bc0dcee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45125, syscall: 202 0x7f74c88619bc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861900 0x2 0x7f74bb15cee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45126, syscall: 202 0x7f74c8861a3c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861a00 0x2 0x7f74ba95bee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45127, syscall: 202 0x7f74c8861abc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861a00 0x2 0x7f74ba15aee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45128, syscall: 202 0x7f74c8861b3c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861b00 0x2 0x7f74b9959ee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45129, syscall: 202 0x7f74c8861bbc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861b00 0x2 0x7f74b9158ee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45130, syscall: 202 0x7f74c8861c3c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861c00 0x2 0x7f74b8957ee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45131, syscall: 202 0x7f74c8861cbc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861c00 0x2 0x7f74b8156ee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45132, syscall: 202 0x7f74c8861d3c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861d00 0x2 0x7f74b7955ee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45133, syscall: 202 0x7f74c8861dbc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861d00 0x2 0x7f74b7154ee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45134, syscall: 202 0x7f74c8861e3c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861e00 0x2 0x7f74b6953ee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45135, syscall: 202 0x7f74c8861ebc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861e00 0x2 0x7f74b6152ee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45136, syscall: 202 0x7f74c8861f3c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861f00 0x2 0x7f74b5951ee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45137, syscall: 202 0x7f74c8861fbc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8861f00 0x2 0x7f74b5150ee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45138, syscall: 202 0x7f74c886203c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8862000 0x2 0x7f74b494fee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45139, syscall: 202 0x7f74c88620bc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8862000 0x2 0x7f74b414eee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45140, syscall: 202 0x7f74c886213c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8862100 0x2 0x7f74b394dee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45141, syscall: 202 0x7f74c88621bc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8862100 0x2 0x7f74b314cee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45142, syscall: 202 0x7f74c886223c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8862200 0x2 0x7f74b294bee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45143, syscall: 202 0x7f74c88622bc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8862200 0x2 0x7f74b214aee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45144, syscall: 202 0x7f74c886233c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8862300 0x2 0x7f74b1949ee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45145, syscall: 202 0x7f74c88623bc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8862300 0x2 0x7f74b1148ee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45146, syscall: 202 0x7f74c886243c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8862400 0x2 0x7f7454d22ee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45147, syscall: 202 0x7f74c88624bc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8862400 0x2 0x7f7454521ee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45148, syscall: 202 0x7f74c886253c 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8862500 0x2 0x7f7453d20ee0 0x7f74ca791360
tid: 45149, syscall: 202 0x7f74c88625bc 0x80 0x5 0x0 0x7f74c8862500 0x2 0x7f745351fee0 0x7f74ca791360
```

Comment: you know about https://github.com/hishamhm/htop ? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: Thanks for the link, but I believe it is nothing to do with `htop` specifically as this can be reproduced with any process which attempts to read from `/proc/ZPID/task/TID/cmdline` where `ZPID` is the zombie process ID.

Comment: @phoxis Looks like reading process fall asleep on the semaphore and didn't wake up later. Have you tried to reproduce this bug in simplified conditions? What are exact conditions needed for bug reproducing ? f.e. if it matters that zombie process have multiple threads or not? Does it happens after some amount of work done in the system or could be reproduced just after restart?

Comment: Could this bug be reproduced constantly or it appears randomly?

Comment: @AlexHoppus: I tried to make a controlled synthetic scenario to create zombies and terminated the parent. The zombie immediately gets reaped by init. Therefore, I cannot reproduce this behaviour at will at another system. In the current state of the system it can be demonstrated at any time, as it  is still in this scenario. We just need to read from `/proc/ZPID/task/TID/cmdline` or similar . After I went through the details, it looks like it is stuck on a semaphore, but I cannot understand why, and if yes, what should be done, as the only semaphore held is by the iscsi daemon.

Comment: @phoxis no no no. The semaphore shown by ipcs are posix semaphores, but what you see in trace is an in-kernel semaphores (in-kernel data structure). They are completely different things. So there is no relation at all.  The behavior you are observing looks like kernel bug.

Comment: @AlexHoppus: Ah! Right, I understood that they are userspace semaphores, I thought they would have been listed using some switches or similar (which it definitely should not). Do you recommend further debugging suggestions?

Comment: @phoxis I think we still need reproducable minimal example (simple C application). After that we could debug linux kernel under qemu.  You say: "I tried to make a controlled synthetic scenario to create zombies and terminated the parent." From your question it seems that bug occurs even if parent of zombie exists, is it so? Or parent need to be killed to reproduce this bug? Have you tried just to create zombie process and cat his /proc/pid/task/tid/cmdline?

Comment: Yes, but I cannot reproduce writing a simple C code. There must be something more complicated going on. In my sample C code, the init takes care of the child. The stated scenario is has happened only once, and in an organic setting. I have access to this setup with the only instance. I will try making an example as I have some hypotheses.
In the present state of that specific system, even before killing the parent, anyone accessing the zombie's proc/tid files were blocking. That is why I thought if the zombie entry gets reparented to init, it may be reaped by init, which it didn't.

Comment: @AlexHoppus: I have updated the post with some new information, it might be interesting